# Disable some functions in PySpark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to prevent users to use certain functions in PySpark SQL?

e.g. Let's say I want to avoid users using function `log` or `rand`, how could I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register an [udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) with the same name as the function that you want to disable and throw an exception in the udf:

```python
def log(s):
    raise Exception("log does not work anymore")
spark.udf.register("log", log)

spark.sql("select *, log(value) from table").show()
```

Result:

```
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
Exception: log does not work anymore
```